# while MVC model value to Javascript get error NaN

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nan

i have a 2 textbox and 1 hidden input.

```js
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

 function GetReceiveAmount(ctr) {
        var x = $("#SendAmount").val();
        var y = $("#SendingExchangeCommission").val();

        alert(x)
        alert(y)

        var total = (x * y).toFixed(2);
        $("#RecieveAmount").val(total);
    }
```

```html
    @model TurkEx.Models.FromTo
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Exchange";
        Layout = "~/Views/LayoutPages/SiteLayout.cshtml";            
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Exchange", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
   <input type="hidden" value="@Model.SendingExchangeCommission" id="SendingExchangeCommission" name="SendingExchangeCommission"/>

     <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="exchange-Amount-label">
                        <label>@TurkEx.Globalization.Exchanges.Resource.Amount</label>
                    </div>
                    <input class="exchange-Amount" id="SendAmount" name="SendAmount" value="@Model.Gateway.MinTransfer" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="return GetReceiveAmount(this);" />
                </div>

  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="exchange-Amount-label">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@TurkEx.Globalization.Exchanges.Resource.Amount</label>
                    </div>
                    <input class="exchange-Amount" id="RecieveAmount" name="RecieveAmount" @*value="@Model.SendingExchangeCommission"*@>
                </div>

 <button type="submit" value="Exchange" class="exchange-button">@TurkEx.Globalization.Exchanges.Resource.Exchange</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
}
```

but when i enter a number textbox 1 (id = SendAmount) textbox 2 shows NaN

if i change y manualy like this "10.1" there is no problem. 
but

var y = $("#SendingExchangeCommission").val();

isnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, there doesn't seem to be anything populating your `y` variable in GetReceiveAmount():

```
// this value will be empty/null if SendingExchangeCommission is empty:
var y = $("#SendingExchangeCommission").val();
```

so when you try to calculate your total here:

```
var total = (x * y).toFixed(2);
```

You might be calculating some numeric value `x` with a null (or some NaN) value, which will either give you 0 or `NaN` as a result:

```
// Some examples to show you how multiplying unknown 
// data types can sometimes give you NaN

// Any number * a String = NaN 
var total = (1 * "someString").toFixed(2); // --> NaN

// Any number * NaN = NaN
var total = (1 * NaN).toFixed(2); // --> NaN

// Any number * Empty String = 0
var total = (1 * " ").toFixed(2); // --> 0.00

// Any number * 0 = 0
var total = (1 * 0).toFixed(2); // --> 0.00
```

So you could check to make sure you are getting a numeric value in `y` (#SendingExchangeCommission) before calculating your total. As you can see from the example, if y (#SendingExchangeCommission) is not empty, but is also not a numeric value, then you will get `NaN` as a result.

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ //

**UPDATE:**  You will want to check if your value inside the input field is in fact, a number. This includes number values with a comma in them. If the system of writing numbers in your country uses a comma instead of a period to separate values (0.0996 vs 0,0996), then you will need to scrub out the comma, because this expression will result in `NaN`:

```
// The comma in the numeric string will result in NaN
var total = (1 * "0,0996").toFixed(2); // --> NaN
```

Where this expression will result in 996.0

```
// This will give you a proper number
var total = (1 * "0.0996").toFixed(2);
```

So the important thing to consider here, is that when you are grabbing values from html text with `.val()` , or .value, you get a string returned to you, so if you want to perform numeric calculations on that string, you need to be sure that the string value has been converted to a number. If a comma is inside the string, then the value can't be properly converted to a number.

Lastly, keep in mind that `parseFloat()` will also give you strange behavior if you feed a comma inside of the numeric values, for example, here is the output of parseFloat("0,0996") vs
parseFloat("0.0996"), notice how the parseFloat with the comma gives you strange behavior, but but the period works as expected:

```
// Results in 0 (zero)
parseFloat("0,0996") // --> 0

// Results in 0.0996
parseFloat("0.0996") // --> 0.0996
```

So I think it might be as simple as the comma in your numeric values that are throwing you off.

Hope this helps.

Comment: function GetReceiveAmount(ctr) {
    var x = $("#SendAmount").val();
    var y = $("#SendingExchangeCommission").val();
    var z = parseFloat(y);

    alert(x)
    alert(y)
    alert(z)
    var total = (x * z).toFixed(2);
    $("#RecieveAmount").val(total);
}

i change like this. if "y" is like 10 no problem. but if "y" is like 0,0996 there is a problem and total = 0

Comment: Ah, I think I see your problem. Look at the updates to my answer to see whyI think its the comma in your numeric values that is throwing you off. Change 0,0996 to 0.0996 and you should start to see the calculations you are looking for. More details as to why can be found in my updated answer.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!  Have fun coding!